# The number shown starts at 10 and increases by a random amount until 60 is reached

Tags: python, random, subroutine

The number shown starts at 10 and increases by a random amount until 60 is reached. Write an subroutine that will achieve this. E.g
10% off.
24% off.
48% off.
60% off.

That is what the code is supposed to do. This is the code I have written so far. It only prints out 0% insted of the full thing

```
import random

#subroutine to show discounts

def Percent(total, Num):
    while total != 60:
        total = total + Num
    return total, Num

#main program
Num = random.randint(0,10)
total = 10
print(total,"% off")
```

ps Im quite new to python so if the fix is really obvious please dont be mean about it :)

Comment: You never call `Percent`.  Is that intended?

Comment: If none of the responses have addressed your question, would you please update it to clarify what's missing?  Alternatively, check out the help page's guidance on [what to do when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You never use your function within your code in first place.
And consider changing your condition for your loop to avoid infinite loop

```
import random

def Percent(total, Num):
    while total <= 60:
        total = total + Num
    return total

#main program
Num = random.randint(0,10)
total = 10
p = Percent(total, Num)
print(p,"% off")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is a way to do what You want to. Please if You do have questions ask! I will try to explain everything as best as I can.

```
import random

starting_pos = 10
print(starting_pos, '% off')
to_reach = 60
total = starting_pos

while total < to_reach:
    max_limit = to_reach - total
    total += random.randint(1, max_limit)
    print(total, '% off')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your written example shows different increment amounts, so the random number generation should be placed inside your function to yield a different value with each call.  You also didn't specify any upper limit on the size of the increments, so I've gone with the assumption that you could conceivably (but not likely) jump straight from 10 to 60.  The following implementation is written as a generator using `yield` rather than `return`.  It always starts with 10 and ends with 60.

```python
import random

def Percent():
    current = 10   # start at 10
    while current < 60:    # keep going while you're below 60
        yield current      # hand back the current value when asked
        # Now generate the next value to be somewhere between the
        # last value and 65.  Anything bigger than 59 will cause it
        # to bail from the loop.  I chose 65 as an upper limit to
        # avoid a lot of dinky little steps as you get close to 60 
        current = random.randint(current + 1, 65)
    # We got something bigger than 59, so just cough up 60 as the outcome.
    yield 60    

#main program
for discount in Percent():
    print(discount,"% off")
```

This produces output such as:

```
10 % off
25 % off
52 % off
58 % off
60 % off
```